# Android Studio Show not the design

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, android-layout

a few ago day´s I Updadet Android Studio and now I can´t see my MainActivity.xml in the Designwindow.The other Design worked perfekt it is only the Main.
[image]
The error Masages are
[image]
I have Install Android Studio new but this helpt not.
I also load backups from my Programm but the some think I can´t see the design, other Apps showed perfekt.When I install an run the App on my testdevice it also worked completly fine.

My Code is

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/design_default_color_primary"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:longClickable="false"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textakku"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/_100"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="55sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.495"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:text="@string/on"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
        android:text="@string/off"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/akkuschutzprogramm"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_error"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/made_by_hutmacher"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonminus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#F44336"
        android:text="@string/minus"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonplus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#4CAF50"
        android:text="@string/Plus"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonminus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/_000"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonplus"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonreset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#FFD600"
        android:text="@string/reset"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonminus"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mactext1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:ems="@android:integer/config_longAnimTime"
        android:hint="@string/mac_adresse"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textakku" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonsave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#FF6D00"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mactext1" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonreset" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonhelp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#2962FF"
        android:text="@string/help"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonreset"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/buttonplus"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/button" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have no idea where the problem is.

Thank You for your help.

Comment: What do the error messages say? (you can view them by clicking on the red warning symbol next to the preview)

Comment: Ok. I paste a Picture in my Question I hope that help you.

Comment: You could try clean project, rebuild project and invalidate caches/restart. Quite often that is a fix for the IDE errors.

Comment: Ok. I find the Button and invalidate caches/restart it. But that dosn´t help. Waht do you mean with rebuild, programm all new? I also think my programm is clean so ther is no extra line of code.